# Uploading an iOS app to the Apple AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

What I'm trying to do is upload an app as version 2.0.1 for the end users. I however get this error message:

> ERROR ITMS-90478: "Invalid Version. The build with the version “2.7”
>   can’t be imported because a later version has been closed for new
>   build submissions. Choose a different version number."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key
>   CFBundleShortVersionString [2.0.1] in the Info.plist file must contain
>   a higher version than that of the previously approved version [2.7]."

The is in the appstore now under version 1.4.3 and I'm trying to upload 2.0.1:

[image]

The iOS builds for 1.4.3 went up to 2.7 already though, is this going to be a problem if I want to be named 2.0.1 in the store? 
[image]

This is what I've filled in for version and buildnumber right now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same experience. I made a build version higher than the previous loaded version.

You don't need to worry about the build number. Make your version as 2.7.1. It will eliminate both the errors. It worked for me.

Comment: Follow the link ,the problem discusssed here.   https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1911266?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

Rest the build version to 1.0 and than try to upload.